# How to call terraform subdirectories as modules in main.tf

Tags: terraform

I have terraform subdirectories contains yaml and json files created under modules, Currently i'm calling them from nain.tf as locals.

```
locals {
        dbs = yamldecode(file("./modules/databases/database.yml"))                             
      }
resource "resourcename" "dbss" {
           for_each = {
            for db in local.dbs.databases: db.id => db 
            if db.environment == var.environment
          }                    
          name     = each.value.name
          comment  = each.value.comment          
}
```

But may i ask if there is a way to call yaml or json files as local module block into my main.tf ?  If so please help me with example or reference?

```
Module databases {
source = "./modules/databases"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I ask what is the context in which you use this code/structure and which providers are you using?

Comment: @KedMardemootoo i'm using snowflake provider , my intention was to deploy database objects using snowflake provider, as you know there will be several hundreds of objects can be in one database, so to simplify directory structure i chose above. hope this helps